# Look Values in column 1 and bring column 2 values

Tags: vba, excel

my data set looks like

```
Col A   
A/05702; A/05724; A/05724;A/05724;A/05725;A/05725;
corresponding Col B
1;1;2;3;1;3;
```

I am trying to get the results as

```
Col C
A/05702;A/5724;A05725
```

and corresponding

```
 ColD1; 1,2,3; 1,3
```

This will look for same values in COLA, then if found COLB values goes to COLD and separated by ","

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is Column A sorted?

Comment: What excel are you using.  Excel just introduced a formula that can do this in February of this year.

Comment: @ScottCraner Even if Kuma doenst use the newest version, could you share that anyways?  ;)

Comment: @ScottCraner - could you share the formula - would beat writing 30 lines of code !

Comment: @Tom I am at work with only 2013 but I believe this entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter as an array will do it: `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF($A$1:$A$6 = $C1, $B$1:$B$6, ""))`

Comment: @Scott, I use 2007, Can this formula modify =IF(A3<>A4,B4,B3&","&B4) , this  only cheks near by cells in Column A

Comment: You will need vba.  see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely leverage the `Dictionary` object from the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library. Add the the reference in your VBE with Tools->References.

Basically, a dictionary allows you to store values against a unique key. You also want to create a set of unique keys but keep appending to the value for that key as you encounter new rows for that key.

Here's the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GenerateSummary()
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim rngTarget As Range
    Dim lngRowCounter As Long
    Dim objData As New Dictionary
    Dim strKey As String, strValue As String

    'get source data
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set rngSource = wsSource.Range("A1:B" & wsSource.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count)

    'analyse data
    For lngRowCounter = 1 To rngSource.Rows.Count
        'get key/ value pair
        strKey = rngSource.Cells(lngRowCounter, 1).Value
        strValue = rngSource.Cells(lngRowCounter, 2).Value
        'if key exists - add to value; else create new key/ value pair
        If objData.Exists(strKey) Then
            objData(strKey) = objData(strKey) & ", " & strValue
        Else
            objData.Add strKey, strValue
        End If
    Next lngRowCounter

    'output dictionary to target range
    'nb dictionary is zero-based index
    Set rngTarget = wsSource.Range("C1")
    For lngRowCounter = 1 To objData.Count
        rngTarget.Cells(lngRowCounter, 1).Value = objData.keys(lngRowCounter - 1)
        rngTarget.Cells(lngRowCounter, 2).Value = objData(objData.keys(lngRowCounter - 1))
    Next lngRowCounter

End Sub
```

### Update

For clarity, I will post screenshots of the data I entered to test this code. So, on my `Sheet2` - which was a totally new and empty of any other data - I've got these entries:

[image]

And then after running the macro, it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but its giving error at the forth row from End Sub.??

Comment: @Kuma try it again please - I changed the code to use late binding to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library which you will have to add to your VB Project.

Comment: @Kuma Keep in mind that `wsSource` refers to `Sheet2` in this code.

Comment: @Robin, I refers to Sheet2 but same problem.??

Comment: @Kuma, If you put your data that you explained in your question into Sheet2 and then run the code, you should get the output you described. I put the code in a `Module` in the VB Editor and added a reference to the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` library. You can add that with the `Tools->References` menu option.

Comment: @Robin I have followed that way but code stop at their, may be sth to do with the version of excell??

Comment: @Kuma, that's strange. I updated my answer to show you the data I have on `Sheet2` - just that data, with no other formulas or other entries. And the output after I run the macro. I'm on Excel 2013. HTH.

Comment: @Robin, Yes screen shot is that i wanted, I will try the code again

Answer (score 2):

You can use this simple UDF:

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr) As String
    Dim d
    For Each d In arr
        If d <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
            TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & d & delim
        End If
    Next d
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - 1)
End Function
```

Make sure to put it in a module attached to the desired workbook and **NOT** in the worksheet code or in ThisWorkbook code.

It is then called like this:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF($A$1:$A$6 = $C1, $B$1:$B$6, ""))
```

Entered as an Array formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

---

**NOTE**

If you have Office 365 the UDF is not needed as it exists in Excel, Just enter the formula as an array.

---

**Alternative**

If you want a formula only approach **AND** your data is sorted then you will need a "helper column".  I put mine in Column C.  In C1 I put:

```
=IF(A2<>A1,B1,B1&"," &C2)
```

Which gave me:

[image]

Then a simple VLOOKUP will return what we want:

```
=VLOOKUP(E1,A:C,3,FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: This way is useful as well. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't NEED vba, you can do this with a pivot table:

```
Row Values:    Col A  
Column Values: Col B  
Values: Min of Col B
```

[image]

You might need a UDF to concatenate the values easily, but that would be pretty simple too:

```
Function JoinWithComma(cells As Range)

    Dim cell As Range, result As String

    For Each cell In cells
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            result = result & cell.Value & ", "
        End If
    Next cell

    If Len(result) > 2 Then
        JoinWithComma = Left(result, Len(result) - 2)
    Else
        JoinWithComma = ""
    End If

End Function
```

[image]