# VBA/UDF, Vlookup to return multiple values]

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to lookup a value and return multiple values (whether it be in the same cell or spread out horizontally pasted in different columns)I have tried the following UDF and continue to get #VALUE as result.

```
Option Explicit
Function LookupCSVResults(lookupValue As Variant, lookupRange As Range, resultsRange As Range) As String

    Dim s As String 'Results placeholder
    Dim sTmp As String  'Cell value placeholder
    Dim r As Long   'Row
    Dim c As Long   'Column
    Const strDelimiter = "|||"  'Makes InStr more robust

    s = strDelimiter
    For r = 1 To lookupRange.Rows.Count
        For c = 1 To lookupRange.Columns.Count
            If lookupRange.Cells(r, c).Value = lookupValue Then
                'I know it's weird to use offset but it works even if the two ranges
                'are of different sizes and it's the same way that SUMIF works
                sTmp = resultsRange.Offset(r - 1, c - 1).Cells(1, 1).Value
                If InStr(1, s, strDelimiter & sTmp & strDelimiter) = 0 Then
                    s = s & sTmp & strDelimiter
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next

    'Now make it look like CSV
    s = Replace(s, strDelimiter, ",")
    If Left(s, 1) = "," Then s = Mid(s, 2)
    If Right(s, 1) = "," Then s = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)

    LookupCSVResults = s 'Return the function

End Function
```

**Formula in cell =LookupCSVResults(Lookup Value, Col of Lookup Value, Col of Return Value)**

Can anyone help trouble shoot this or have another UDF that will provide similar result? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to return them into the same cell look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37923950/look-values-in-column-1-and-bring-column-2-values I have a quick dirty function that will help.  The problem is that you can't change the value of other cells with a function.  You can return and array and highlight the desired output cells and hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter to enter the formula as an array into all those cells at once.

Comment: Hi Scott, it doesnt need to be in the same cell, having a horizontal array would also be useful. Just can't seem to get this function to work.

Comment: Please post the data that you are using, It works just fine for me. see here: http://imgur.com/a/xUDBB

Comment: It just worked when I tried sample data , so could it be my workbook format?

Comment: without seeing the data I could not tell.

Comment: But there is nothing wrong with the code and it does what it should.  So the fault is in the data or the execution.