# Passing a VBA array to a formula

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have two rows of data looking like this:

[image: Data]

I am trying to return all the position numbers for each ID in an array. I have tried

```
={IF(A2:A562=E2,B2:B562)}
```

But it fails whenever the ID I am searching for is not the first in column A. (I did try to sort column A with no luck).

So I have come up with this workaround: instead I would use this formula

```
={INDEX(B2:B562,positions(E2))}
```

where `positions` is a VBA function that return an array of rows that match specified ID. The function `positions` is coded so that it return a `Variant`. But it seems that the VBA Array is not passing to the formula in excel. When I evaluate the formula, `positions(E2)` is equal to 0. (I have checked in VBA, and my array is correctly populated).

So how do I make my formula correctly interpret the VBA array?

UPDATE: Here is my code:

```
Function positions(idrange As Range) As Variant
Dim V As Variant
Dim l, nb As Integer
Dim id As Double

nb = 4
ReDim V(nb) As Variant

id = idrange.Value
Set cible = Sheet2.Range("B1")
For l = 1 To nb
    Set cible = Sheet2.Columns(2).Find(What:=id, After:=cible, _
                LookIn:=xlValues)

    V(l) = cible.Row - 1   
Next l
positions = Application.Transpose(V)

End Function
```

UPDATE 2: Here is the desired output

[image]

Comment: Post your VBA code.

Comment: So what is the desired output?

Comment: @ScottCraner, say I am looking at the first ID. I would like it to return {3,5,7}

Comment: Okay next question:  What excel are you using?

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37923950/look-values-in-column-1-and-bring-column-2-values

Comment: @ScottCraner, sorry. Excel 2013 (VBA 7.1)

Comment: @ScottCraner, Thanks. But I want to store the result as an array in Excel not as a string (ie: range(A3:A5)={3,5,7}). And my question was how to make the index formula correctly interpret the array from function positions.

Comment: To what end?  What will you do with this array?  Like I asked what is the final output and into one cell or many?  Their may be an easier way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this array formula in F2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$562,MATCH(1,($A$2:$A$562=$E2)*(COUNTIF($E$2:E2,$B$2:$B$562)=0),0)),"")
```

Confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Then copy over and down sufficient to cover all the data.

[image]

---

EDIT #1

If you can sort the data then you can avoid the array formula and use this normal formula:

```
=IF(COLUMN(A:A) <= COUNTIF($A:$A,$E2),INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($E2,$A:$A,0)+COLUMN(A:A)-1),"")
```

[image]

Comment: One more thing: what if two ID could assume the same position?

Comment: Not sure I understand.  Are you saying that the cell has two ID's?

Comment: Let say A values (in column B) are 1,1,7,10

Comment: You now have moved into vba territory.  I would ask a new question with the added data and expected outcome.  I doubt that a formula will be able to do what you want.

Comment: OK, I'll start a new question

Answer (score 2):

Drawing on [Is it possible to fill an array with row numbers which match a certain criteria without looping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921350/is-it-possible-to-fill-an-array-with-row-numbers-which-match-a-certain-criteria/13061123#13061123), you can do this with array and VBA as so:

1. This line `Filter(Application.Transpose(Application.Evaluate("=IF(A2:A100=OFFSET(E2," & lngCnt - 1 & ",0), (B2:B100),""x"")")), "x", False)` returns a string of the matching B values

> "1","4","7","10" for A2

2. This line `[e2].Offset(lngCnt - 1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(x) + 1) = Split(Join(x, "|"), "|")` puts the string to each array

*code*

```
Sub GetEm()

Dim lngCnt As Long
'range of your codes from E2 down
y = [E2:E4]

For lngCnt = 1 To UBound(y)
     x = Filter(Application.Transpose(Application.Evaluate("=IF(A2:A100=OFFSET(E2," & lngCnt - 1 & ",0), (B2:B100),""x"")")), "x", False)
    [e2].Offset(lngCnt - 1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(x) + 1) = Split(Join(x, "|"), "|")
Next
End Sub
```

[image]