# Merge values from column if another column contains a certain value

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate values based on the value in a different column
If any value in B = D1, then E1 equals all values in A where matches are in B, and so on.

A simple idea is Column A has a list of names, Column B has their favorite color.  In Column C is a list of the colors, and in Column D, each cell is fully populated with all the names that match that color.

So far when I try this, I either get just the value in that row, or it returns double or not all the values.

Comment: show your code along with its issues

Comment: please at least give an example table of data and wanted result, along with your attempts this far

Comment: See my answer in the link of the dupicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37923950/look-values-in-column-1-and-bring-column-2-values